# how to edit state based on country using php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I fetch state from selected country in edit time?

This is for country:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="select2 form-control custom-select " style="width: 100%; height:36px;" name="country" onChange="getState(this.value);" id="country">
    <option>Select Country</option>
    <?php foreach($countries as $coun) { 
            foreach($ed as $edit) /*edit mode*/
            {

                if($edit->country_id==$coun->id)
                {
        ?>

                    <option value="<?php  echo $coun->id;  ?>" selected="selected"> <?php echo $coun->name; ?> </option>
        <?php 
            }}

                ?>
                    <option value="<?php  echo $coun->id;  ?>"> <?php echo $coun->name; ?> </option>
                <?php


    } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is for state:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="select2 form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;" name="state" id="state-list" onChange="getCity(this.value);">
    <option>Select State</option>

    </select>
    </div>
```

```js
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getState.php",
        data:'country_id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#state-list").html(data);
            //getCity();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: where is your `getState.php` page ?

Comment: What exactly is not working ? Also check the way you are passing data: `data:'country_id='+val,`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getState.php",
        data:{country_id:val},
        success: function(data){
            $("#state-list").html(data);
            //getCity();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @ankita that's great.